# Why is my flag accepted and the question still alive?

Tags: support, flags

My flag has been accepted, so why isn't this question closed?

**Q:** [Developing a mobile app to store images](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27318267/3453226)

**Flag:**

> [image]

---

**UPDATE** It was just closed as *off-topic*, so why am I not in the voters list?

[image]

Comment: `It was just closed as off-topic, so why am I not in the voters list?`  Did you vote to close?  Nope, you flagged to close.  That only shows people who cast an actual vote to close.  Also, "Hi mom! I'm in a Meta screenshot!"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Recommend closure flags get marked as helpful the moment another user casts a vote to close for the same reason *or* the question gets closed for any reason.

You are not in the close notice because you cast a *flag* to close. Users with less than 3,000 reputation can only flag them, which bumps them into the Close Votes queue so those with full close voting privileges can look at (and potentially close) the question.